# Expanding a OData function call result throws exception since upgrading generator to 2.4

Tags: c#, odata

I've updated OData Client T4 Template from 2 to 2.3 and this is no longer working.

```
 _container.Users.GetLoggedInUser().Expand(x => x.Debtor);
```

This is the new generated code

```
    [global::Microsoft.OData.Client.OriginalNameAttribute("GetLoggedInUser")]
    public static global::Something.OData.Client.SomethingPortal.Data.UserSingle GetLoggedInUser(this global::Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceQuery<global::Something.OData.Client.SomethingPortal.Data.User> source)
    {
        if (!source.IsComposable)
        {
            throw new global::System.NotSupportedException("The previous function is not composable.");
        }

        return new global::Something.OData.Client.SomethingPortal.Data.UserSingle(source.CreateFunctionQuerySingle<global::Something.OData.Client.SomethingPortal.Data.User>("Default.GetLoggedInUser", false));
    }
```

This was what was generated by version 2

```
    public static global::Something.OData.Client.SomethingPortal.Data.UserSingle GetLoggedInUser(this global::Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceQuery<global::Something.OData.Client.SomethingPortal.Data.User> source)
    {
        if (!source.IsComposable)
        {
            throw new global::System.NotSupportedException("The previous function is not composable.");
        }

        string parameterString = global::Microsoft.OData.Client.Serializer.GetParameterString(source.Context);
        return new global::Something.OData.Client.SomethingPortal.Data.UserSingle(source.Context, source.GetPath("Default.GetLoggedInUser" + parameterString), false);
    }
```

And this is what the schema for this function looks like

```
  <Function Name=""GetLoggedInUser"" IsBound=""true"">
    <Parameter Name=""bindingParameter"" Type=""Collection(SomethingPortal.Data.User)"" />
    <ReturnType Type=""SomethingPortal.Data.User"" />
  </Function>
```

The exception thrown is

> Message = "Individual properties can only be selected from a single resource or as part of a type. Specify a key predicate to restrict the entity set to a single instance or project the property into a named or anonymous type."

Is this a bug in 2.4 or is there a change I need to make somewhere?

Thanks

Comment: Created a temporary workaround by adding the working method as an extension method outside of the generated code.

Comment: Thanks for report this issue. it should be a bug in OData client. Opened an issue https://github.com/OData/odata.net/issues/357 to track it.